# Is there any way to tell which PouchDB plugins are currently loaded?

Tags: plugins, pouchdb

The title pretty much says it all.

Is there any way to get a list of loaded PouchDB plugins?  Or failing that, is there any way to check if a specific plugin is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pouchdb just adds plugins to its prototype, so if you don't mind seeing some built-ins:

```
> location.href
"http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/"

> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(PouchDB.prototype)
Array[11]
0: "constructor"
1: "query"
2: "viewCleanup"
3: "replicate"
4: "sync"
5: "upsert"
6: "putIfNotExists"
7: "createIndex"
8: "find"
9: "getIndexes"
10: "deleteIndex"
length: 11
__proto__: Array[0]


> "find" in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(PouchDB.prototype)
true
```